# Video Card support problem on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, opengl, 3d

I've been working with 3d rendering programs on my laptop. I'm using a program called Avizo by fei the program has linux and windows support.
I'm using my dual-boot computer. On the windows my the program works fine, but on the Ubuntu it says it couldn't find any Mb on my GPU. I have an integrated intel video card i915.

```
➜  ~ glxinfo| grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 17.2.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 17.2.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

checking the requirements I found that i need at least OpenGL 2.1.\
Is there a way to update my driver so that my computer will use OpenGL 2.1 instead of 2.0?

Comment: You are using 2.1.

Comment: then why is it written there OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: OpenGL ES it is another story. It is for embedded systems.

Comment: you are right, for some reason only some of the options are not available some are. I'll see with what I can work. I can close this question.